# ActiveModel Serializers no longer work after upgrading to Rails 4.2.0.rc3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

ActiveModelSerializers no longer work after upgrading to Rails 4.2.0.rc3

Since upgrading the Rails 4.2.0.beta1/2/3/rc3 my [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) are not being used.

The only way to make them work is to call the serializer manually and render the resulting output (#as_json).

The serialisers previously worked with `respond_with`, is there any way to regain that functionality?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/641) about the problem, for now you can try to to use the git version directly until the versions are officially out and the compatibility fixed.

```
gem "active_model_serializers", github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers", branch: "0-8-stable"
```

Comment: I did look at the issues hoping to find something, but didn't realise there was more than one page :) Thank you for taking the time to respond, much appreciated :)